# UART serial output pin held high, can't read usable information

Tags: serial, uart

I'm working on a home automation project where my Pi will be interfacing several picaxe chips using an UART serial connection.

Even though I've installed Minicom on the Raspberry Pi and disabled the boot messages, the output is still being held high, resulting in garbled text appearing on the terminal on my PC.

Is there any way to have the Pi hold the serial line low until there is an active data transmission? I am using an AXE027 serial cable (uses an ftdi-based chip) to read data from the serial port.

Comment: The TX line should be high until the start bit when it will go low.  That's what serial links do.  If you want to use some other protocol you'll have to bit bang.

Comment: @joan I did a bit of research and it turns out that the Raspberry Pi might not be using the same RS-232 protocol. Would it be possible to use 'bit banging' to solve this?

Comment: Possibly.  What protocol is being used?

Comment: Bitbandaging on Raspbian doesn't work well,  because it is event driven (the timings are out of synch). Even tuning your script will cause unforeseen problems. I have noticed the same problem(Arduino bridge), and just don't use the Pi UART for anything... because its a nightmare.I have not worked out how to use it properly yet. I2C works well.

Comment: @ppumkin I see what you mean about the timings being out of sync. I've successfully got my Picaxe 08m2 to send a test message to the Raspberry Pi, after changing the transmission method from 'Negative' 2400 baud to 'True' 2400 baud. I think I'll look into i2c communication instead.

Comment: @joan I was wrong, it uses the same RS232, but the bits are sent and recieved flipped

Comment: Hmm interesting about the True baud. There must be a setting for flipped bits. I admit I have not looked that much into the problem, mostly because it was annoying me that it didn't work.I used a FTDI USB instead to work with my Arduino's No problem at all.

Comment: If the signal is inverted then just buy or build an inverter.

Comment: The Pi's UART is quite happy at 230400 bps and I've bit banged TX at 1.25 Mbps. There is no reason to use the relatively slow I2C.

Comment: @joan Would an opamp be fast enough to do the inversion?

Comment: Not my field, but I'd be amazed if it wasn't.  Have a look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/how-to-invert-a-digital-signal